# How to know which is the RDD type inferred by Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-1.6

I was trying the follow example

```
val lista = List(("a", 3), ("a", 1), ("b", 7), ("a", 5))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(lista)
```

Then in the shell I get the following

```
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[40] at parallelize at <console>:30
```

But for some reason I still haven't figured out I was able to execute this sentence

```
val resAgg = rdd.aggregateByKey(new HashSet[Int])(_+_, _++_)
```

Getting this in the shell

```
resAgg: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int])] = ShuffledRDD[41] at aggregateByKey at <console>:32
```

So I have some questions:

1.- What is the real RDD type of the var named rdd? because in the shell it shows is of the type org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] but looking on the API the RDD class does not have a method aggregateByKey. By the way JavaPairRDD class does it have the aggregateByKey method

2.- How Can I verify/know the real type of a RDD

3.- What is that ParallelCollectionRDD showed up? I looked for it on github and I found is a private class so I guess is that the reason why is does not appears on the scala API, but what it is for?

I was using Spark 1.6.2

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is the effect of **[implicit conversion](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html)**:

- `rdd` *does* have the type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]`
- When you try calling `aggregateByKey` and it isn't there for this type, compiler looks for some implicit conversion into some type that does - and finds [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1806) conversion into `PairRDDFunctions`:

  ```
  implicit def rddToPairRDDFunctions[K, V](rdd: RDD[(K, V)])
    (implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K] = null): PairRDDFunctions[K, V] = {
    new PairRDDFunctions(rdd)
  }
  ```
- Then, [`PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L162) is invoked.

As for your last question:

> What is that ParallelCollectionRDD

RDD is an abstract class with many subclasses, this is one of them. Generally speaking, each subclass is in charge of different actions done on the RDD, e.g. reading/writing/shuffling/checkpointing etc. This specific type is used when calling `SparkContext.parallelize` - meaning, it is used to parallelize a collection from the driver program. Indeed, it's private and you shouldn't generally care about which subtype of RDD you actually have at hand.

Comment: Thx for your answer but still I have a doubt regarding to aggregationByKey method invocation. How is the relation between RDD and PairRDDFunctions classes?
I have red this on the API about PairRDDFunctions  "Extra functions available on RDDs of (key, value) pairs through an implicit conversion."
but I mean I still don´t see how this classes have a relationship (except by Logging Trait) each other. Would you mind give me a clue or a reference to try to understand it. 
Maybe it is a scala property I haven't red yet, isn't it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no direct relation (i.e. none of them extends / implements the other), read more about implicit conversions in the link I've just added. Basically, the implicit conversion let's you call `rdd.aggregateAndSave(...)` as if you were calling `new PairRDDFunctions(rdd).aggregateAndSave(...)`

Comment: Thank you again, I have to study about scala implicit functions, now I see it.